# Javax Hibernate Validator for enum

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, enums, annotations

I want use annotations like `@Null` or `@NotBlank` on an enum type. Here is the pojo and enum class:

```
public final class Request {
    @NotBlank(message="Value should not be null or empty.")
    private InputType type;
}

public enum InputType {
    RTS,
    ERJ
}
```

Those annotations work if `type` is a string. But when I change it to `InputType` I get the following error:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'controllers.model.InputType'. Check configuration for 'type'
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:229)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:310)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:244)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:617)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:524)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:492)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:407)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:205)
    org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:866)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:268)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
```

Any idea how to validate enums like strings?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of [@NotBlank](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html), the annotation only works on strings. That makes sense as it evaluates whitespace in the object. [@NotEmpty](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html) would work on some collection types too, but still no strings. What you really seem to need is the plain [@NotNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) contained in the standard bean validation API.